# Cannot login to drupal in Chrome or Firefox, but Safari works

Tags: drupal, authentication, drupal-6

Problem: Login is not working in Firefox and Chrome but it does in Safari.

Details:
We just moved a drupal 6 installation to another host and followed some steps:

> Moved
>   sites/site1/Themes/themeFolder
>   to
>   sites/all/Themes/themeFolder
>
> Made these changes in
>   page-node-NNN.tpl.php files (searched
>   all files in themes/themeFolder):
>
> 1) find: /oldpath/ replace: /newpath/
>   2) find: oldsubdomain.     replace: www.
>   3) find: .com/sites/  replace: .com/newpath/sites/

Then as I login it fails in any browser when the wrong information is entered but when it is correct it simply redirects to that users profile page...and then nothing. There are no admin menus, no edit buttons for content and **it is a though it authenticated but somehow never stored anything** that would help with the authentication later.

*The strange thing is that for 3 people with three different systems Firefox and Chrome don't work. But Safari does. We have ruled out that it is the database or old cookies.*

**Any one have a good guess?**

Comment: Did you clear the cache and run cron?

Answer (score 1):

Have you checked the `$cookie_domain` variable in your settings.php? It should be either commented out or adjusted to your new domain. (I faintly remember Safari having a slightly different cookie domain handling model than other browsers - not sure though.)

You could also check the cookies set by the new site in the different browsers directly and compare for differences.

Another (wild) guess would be the date/time setting on the new host. It is pretty unlikely, but if the date is off to the past, the expiration date of the cookies will be off to, and the browsers might deal differently with that.

Also, you surely have flushed all Drupal caches after the move, have you?

Comment: `$cookie_domain` only is for when you want to be able to login across a drupal installation that has many different sites and enable the cookie to be set under one domain. It is uncommented in my settings.php. Haven't been able to check the rest. Tomorrow

Comment: We also checked the date/time settings and the cache several times. Still no luck...

Answer (score 1):

I could login to my client's Drupal site with Firefox but not with any other browser. It turned out my client server clock was off by 2 years. Henrik mentioned this already but I can confirm that was the cause for me.

Answer (score 1):

OK< so this is an old post and while the notes here were good, they did not completely resolve my similar issue.  In the end, I found that my inability to log in was due not to a corrupt sessions table, but instead due to a lack of disk space on the server.  So, if all else fails, log in to your server (linux, etc.) and run df -h which will display your disk availability stats.  If you find that you're very low on space, run this command:

find / -type f -size +50000k -exec ls -lh {} \; | awk '{ print $9 ": " $5 }'

(this will find all files in excess of 50MB, a good place to start if you're doing a lot of logging, etc.).  Then go through and remove the files you don't need (or simply add more disk).

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem which was caused by a corrupt sessions table in the database. I fixed it by repairing the sessions table following the advice in the article at http://www.go2linux.org/cannot-login-into-drupal-table-corrupted

Answer (score -2):

Wow okay I found out one thing that will cause it to not work is setting your default windows time out of sync. If you change it to several hours ahead or behind time it could cause you to not be able to login to your website. Restore it back to the defaults and clear your cache and cookies and then close out the browser and restart it. It worked for me!